# How to debug magento files using Xdebug in eclipse

Tags: magento, magento-1.7, magento-1.5, magento-1.6

I am new to xdebug using with magento. When I place break point at first line, it breaks at index.php and continues fine. But when I want to test the login function or menu navigation , I am placing the breaking points at "class Mage_Page_Block_Html_Topmenu extends Mage_Core_Block_Template", But it didnt stops here and continues. So exactly where I have to keep break points?? Do I need to place points in .phtml files? I am not sure where I have to place. So can anyone help me on debugging with magento.

Comment: It should make no difference in which file you place your breakpoint. Xdebug can be used in every file where php code is executed. I think there is something wrong with your xdebug configuration or the code with your breakpoint wasn't executed. Try to put one in your index.php itself an see if it is triggered.

Comment: @SimonH If I place break point in index.php, the code execution stops at that point and continues when I press F5 button only. It works upto index.php and continues to mage.php. After it stops the debugging.

Comment: Sounds like xdebug is set up correctly. For non eclipse users: F5 is for stepping into. You should see some more files if you don't get an exception. What does your browser display after the debbuging finished?

Comment: If I place break point in login.phtml, After completion of loading of home page, if I click on login link, then it simply loads login page. It didnt stops at the point where I have been placed break point.

Comment: Did you make sure you are in the right theme? Try to place a `die()` statement where you put your breakpoint to find out.

Answer (score 3):

I am sorry for this answer if you simply just want to use xdebug!

You won´t have much success with xdebug, because from my point of view its to slow to work with. I would recommend to use

`Mage::log($var)` or `Mage::logException($var)`

and just do a

`tail -f on var/log/system.log`  or `tail -f on var/log/exception.log`.

On `Varien_Object` classes you can use something like `Mage::log($product->debug())` to give reduced log output. As you might know the position in code where you want to debug this is maybe best practice.

Please make sure you have debug output enabled in Magento.

Comment: so cant we debug our magento application with eclipse?

Comment: Of course you can. Just in case  exceptions are thrown its caught by the Magento Exception handler. But it makes little sense as you will never step through the framework flow but debugging at a certain class or file. So Mage::log is more than enough and much faster.

Comment: Yes, xdebug slows your application down massively. But it can be configured to be only active when needed using `xdebug.profiler_enable_trigger=1` in php.ini. I'm not using eclipse so I can't tell if it can be used.